# Dealing with session in PHP across Linux user accounts

Tags: php, session

On a Linux-hosted sever, I have the same web app installed on two user's accounts (`http://host.com/~linux_user`)

As you might guess, I have problems because sessions are shared between user accounts.

From now on, I'll store them as a session array (`$_SESSION['linux_user']['my_data']`).

Is this a good approach?

Comment: You can change the location session files are stored with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php  which would let you have separate session files for each account's copy of the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get rid of the problem with using a custom session handler, which handles session storage as you want it to : database, memcache...

More info here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Answer (score 1):

"From now on, I'll store as session array $_SESSION['linux_user']['my_data']. Is this a good approach?"

No, as those session variables will only be available in one user account. What you need is a single-sign-on technology, like if you want to stay logged in over multiple domains. For example you may use [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

Or you store the PHP-session at an explicit location (within the filesystem or in a database).

But why/how do you have the PHP-app installed into two different user accounts? If I set up an Apache web-server, it runs as a separate user…